# Detect UIImageView Touch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

How would you detect and run an action when a `UIImageView` is touched? 
This is the code that I have so far:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) { 
    var touch: UITouch = UITouch()
    if touch.view == profileImage {
        println("image touched")
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `true`. I believe it's `false` by default for `UIImageView`.

Comment: @AdamPro13 it still does not work with the code that I have above.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can put an `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside your `UIImageView` using Interface Builder or in code (as you want), I prefer the first. Then you can put an `@IBAction` and handle the tap inside your `UIImageView`, Don't forget to set the `UserInteractionEnabled` to `true` in Interface Builder or in code.

```
@IBAction func imageTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("Image Tapped.")
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: How can I pass extra argument in "imageTapped" function?

Answer (score 26):

You can detect touches on a `UIImageView` by adding a [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer) to it.

It's important to note that by default, a `UIImageView` has its `isUserInteractionEnabled` property set to false, so you must set it explicitly in storyboard or programmatically.

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped)))
}

@objc private func imageTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("image tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
        if touch.view == profileImage {
    println("image touched")
}

}


override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
        if touch.view == profileImage {
    println("image released")
}

}
```

Comment: Need to add profileImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true in viewDidLoad() method.