# 1. Making UI image to work as a button. 2. Making UI image to change it's color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiimageview

As I understand, UI buttons may only have rectangular or round-ish shapes. I have a set of images of different shapes (e.g. pants, t-shirt, beard etc.) and each of them should work as a button. How do I make UI Image to work as a button?

Second question: how do I make mentioned UI images to change color. I'm building an app where you can describe your look using paper doll kinda tool ( https://www.behance.net/gallery/49171187/ICEBREAKER-(work-in-progress) ). You tap an element > it calls a keyboard where each key represents a color > after you tap a key and choose a color the element you've tapped before changes it's color accordingly.

Thank you

Comment: `UIImage` is not a view and you can not get a touch event on it directly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect UIImageView Touch in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30990902/6689101)

Comment: Why not simply use your image with `UIButton`?

Answer (score 1):

UIImage doesn't inherit from UIControl like UIButton ( UIControl is a class that define the behavior of all visual elements that are used for handling action. )

A way for triggering an action when the user clicks on an UIImage, is to create a gesture ( like a pinch or a touch ) and adding it to the relative UIImageView.

```
func mySelector(gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print(123)
}

override func viewDidLoad(){

    let myImage = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
    let myView = UIImageView(image: myImage)
    myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let touchGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector((mySelector)))

    myView.addGestureRecognizer(touchGesture)
}
```

An important thing to remember is that by default, for UIImageView's instances, myView.isUserInteractionEnabled is set to false, so even if you are going to add a gesture recognizer, it will not be handled.

**EDIT**

I'm supposing that you already did the keyboard with every colors! 
So when you click on the color, a selector is called.
 If you change your myImage declaration of the answer above with

`let myImage = UIImage(named:"yourImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`, you can change your color easily, setting inside the called selector the tint color of the imageView :

```
myView.tintColor = selectedColor
```

That it is!

Comment: Looks super neat, I'll try that! Appreciate it. But before I have to fix a design issue I've just noticed. I plan to put every set of images on a separate horizontal scroll view (1. hairstyle, 2. facial hair, 3. tops, 4. bottoms). For now it looks like that scroll views will intersect (hair with facial hair, tops with bottoms etc.) so I need to remove these intersections.

Answer (score 1):

As I see the images are totally different and shapes are complex. If you want your custom shape (pants, beard etc.) to act like a button and to recognize touches not only in rectangular area there's a "hard way" but you can achieve the 100% result.

**The "Hard Way" (Overkill)**

You can subclass UIButton and create bezier paths for different shapes, in drawrect you will need to fill path with color and handle touches in hitTest method.

Here's an approximate algorithm of what you should do to achieve the result you want.

```
import UIKit

class CustomShapeButton: UIButton {

    lazy var pantsShapeBezierPath: UIBezierPath = {
        // Crate new path
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        // Set starting point for path
        path.move(to: CGPoint)

        // Add lines with:
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint)

        // Add curves with:
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint, controlPoint1: CGPoint, controlPoint2: CGPoint)

        // Add arcs with:
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool)

        // Close path with (finalize path):
        path.close()

        return path
    }()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        // Set shape filling color
        UIColor.red.setFill()

        // Fill the shape
        pantsShapeBezierPath.fill()
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        // Handling touch events 

        if (pantsShapeBezierPath.contains(point)) {
            return self

        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Please check out the documentation for UIButton:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton

and UIBezierPath:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath

**The simple (best) way.**

For simpler solution just use UIButton with its rectangular touch area. It's made for cases where user interaction takes place :]

drag an `IBAction` from `UIButton` in storyboard to your code

create a `collectionView` in in your viewController or in xib

set it's frame to bottom area when you want to see it:

```
var collectionHeight: CGFloat = 210.0
var frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(self.view.bounds.size.height - collectionHeight), width: CGFloat(self.view.bounds.size.width), height: collectionHeight)
```

and set it hidden when you don't:

```
var frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(self.view.bounds.size.height), width: CGFloat(self.view.bounds.size.width), height: collectionHeight)
```

animate frame change on button taps. Should be something like this:

```
func setCollectionViewHidden(hide: Bool) {
            let collectionHeight = 210.0
            let yPosition = hide ? self.view.bounds.size.height : self.view.bounds.size.height - 210
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33) {
                var updatedFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: yPosition, width: CGFloat(self.view.bounds.size.width), height: collectionHeight)
                self.collectionView.frame = updatedFrame
            }
        }
```

set the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` how you want, please refer to the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout

you can just set an array of color as the dataSource

implement the  `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` delegate method you can make the button `tintColor` change.

That's an approximate algorithm of what you should do. Good luck, bro!

Comment: What do you think about this solution? Seems much easier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990902/detect-uiimageview-touch-in-swift

Comment: Also, what about the second question, how would you solve this part? Spasibo

Comment: The point is not to reinvent the bicycle :] I advise to use UIButton because it is a subclass of UIControl https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol
it has the proper API to handle user interaction. You don't need to add gestureRecognizer, set userInteractionEnabled etc., just add a UIButton and set the button's imageView image that's it. It will be the simplest solution and it think it will suit your needs.

Comment: @Rdk Updated my answer about the second part.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your `.xcassets` file, set your images to render as templates:

   [image: render as template image]
2. Use `UIButtons` and set the images as needed.
3. Set the `tintColor` property of the `UIButton` to the desired color.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Making UI image work as button:

You can easily give UI Image or any other view the same capabilities as a button/control by adding a **gesture recognizer** to it

There is an example from Apple in their [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html)

Section `Create a Gesture Recognizer`