# How can I highlight a UIImageView from an array when the view is tapped/clicked

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimageview

I have an array of UIImageViews (8 of them) and I want to highlight which ever one is tapped or clicked. NOTE: It doesn't have to be highlighted I am open to other way as well. As you will see in my code I tried a different way.

As you will see below I tried to access the index.layer.borderColor and then created and if else statement. next I created a UITapGuestureRecognizer function and called this in the viewDidLoad. App is crashing with an "out of bounds" error.

```
func setHandleTap() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        imageArray[index(ofAccessibilityElement: 0..<7)].addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

        @objc func handleTap() { // this funtion checks to see what the boarder image is and chages it to other once tapped.
        if imageArray[index(ofAccessibilityElement: 0..<7)].layer.borderColor == #colorLiteral(red: 0.01680417731, green: 0.1983509958, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor {
            imageArray[index(ofAccessibilityElement: 0..<7)].layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
        }else{
            imageArray[index(ofAccessibilityElement: 0..<7)].layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.01680417731, green: 0.1983509958, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

I call the setHandelTap() in ViewDidLoad hoping it would run allowing the image to be highlighted.

Comment: May I know how you are showing your UIImageView?

Comment: Oh I did forget to add that. the array/collection of the UIImageViews is called imageArray

Comment: I am not entirely sure how does ofAccessibilityElement works, but I don't think it should be used that way. I think that function takes an element as parameter and return you the index.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right I was just messing around to see if I could get it to work. For the single imageView it would be something like this imageView.layer.borderColor = Color.cgColor but I am not sure how to do that with the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through the array should be enough for this.

Maybe something like this in your *handleTap()*:

```
let desiredColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.01680417731, green: 0.1983509958, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
for imageView in imageArray {
    if imageView.layer.borderColor == desiredColor {
        imageView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor // Sets it to Black Color.
    }
 }
```

*Note: By the way there is no need for the else code because the current color is already the color you wanted to set on the else*

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Thanks so much!!! Last question though, what would the tapGesture function need to be now. How would I tap into the .addGestureRecognizer

Comment: Glad it helped you.

You may have a look at these answers over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990902/detect-uiimageview-touch-in-swift/30991103

Comment: So I went through those answers but I am unable to get this working. I created the tap fiction from the storyboard and linked it in my code then put that for statement inside. Still not doing anything when UIImageView is tapped